# Confused About Definition of a Limit Proof

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

I'm working on $\epsilon-\delta$ limit proofs, and there's something about the proof I don't get. Currently doing a proof for  $\lim_{x\to 3} (2x-1) = 5$.

The first part of the definition says "if ($0 < x-a < \delta$)". In the case of approaching a, $3$, from the right, positive side, $x-3$ will be positive and more then zero. But from the other side, $x < a$, so $x-a$ would be $< 0$, which doesn't meet that part of the definition.

Comment: When limits are defined we have, for given $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\quad\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$
Then, we say that $L$ is the limit of $f$ when $x$ tends to $a$.

Comment: [Definition of limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit). The internet is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a limit normally involves absolute values; in other words, you need to prove that for ever $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ with the property that
$$0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$
The version you wrote in your question has parentheses where there should be absolute value bars.  If the absolute value bars were in there, the problem you are having would be moot, because $|x-a|$ is non-negative regardless of whether $x-a$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Ohhh. Ok. Teacher needs to work on how straight they draw their lines...